# How to improve the AUC scores of my link prediction algorithm?

Tags: python, prediction

I am exploring a link prediction algorithm, but my AUC scores change every time I run it and it is always very low. It varies from 50 to around 72. I was wondering if there is a way to improve their performance. I think it might be related to how I am defining the training set, but I am not sure.

```
    # Resource Allocation
    #Remove 20% of the edges
proportion_edges=.2
edge_subset = random.sample(G.edges(), int(proportion_edges*G.number_of_edges()))

    #Create a copy of the graph and remove the edges
G_train= G.copy()
G_train.remove_edges_from(edge_subset)

    #Make prediction    
pred_ra = list(nx.resource_allocation_index(G_train))
score_ra, label_ra = zip(*[(s, (u,v) in edge_subset) for (u,v,s) in pred_ra])

#Compute the ROC AUC Score of Resource Allocation
fpr_ra, tpr_ra, _= metrics.roc_curve(label_ra, score_ra)
auc_ra = roc_auc_score(label_ra, score_ra)
print(auc_ra)
```